# Update status in all sub with the master DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, data-views, sfmc-business-unit, unsubscribe

I have a question about the unsusbcribe in the all subscriber.
When my customer decided to optout in the website of my client, the information of this unsubscribe goes up in service cloud, then in the data synchronised account of the BU and finish in my master DE.
But the information does not go up in the all subscriber , the status of my customer stay "active".

So the customer is optin in the all sub but he is optout in the master DE and i would like to change this status to active from unsubscribe in the all sub.

How can I link my master DE with the all subscriber to update the all subscriber when a customer change is optin or optout?
I need to do that for the four BU.

I did a test with my account, I am optout in the master DE and optin in the all sub, i tried this sql :

```sql
Select 
a.SubscriberKey as subkeyMAL,
a.PersonEmail,
'Unsubscribed' as Status,
a.DateLastNewsletterOptin__c,
a.DateLastNewsletterOptout__C,
a.NewsletterOptIn__c,
buUnsub.BusinessUnitID,
buUnsub.SubscriberID,
buUnsub.SubscriberKey,
buUnsub.UnsubDateUTC,
buUnsub.UnsubReason
FROM Master_DE a
LEFT JOIN ent._BusinessUnitUnsubscribes AS buUnsub  ON buUnsub.SubscriberKey = a.SubscriberKey
WHERE
buUnsub.BusinessUnitID = 'XXXX' 
and a.NewsletterOptIn__c = '0'
and and buUnsub.UnsubDateUTC is null
```

I have as a result 0 records therefor I'm optout in the master DE, so "newsletteroptin = 0" , but optin (active) in the all sub.

Do you have an idea to help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a **Data Extract** of the master data extension, **File Transfer** from the safehouse to the SFMC sFTP, and **Import** it in to All Subscribers. Put this all in an automation in Automation Studio and run it nightly.

You should only need these fields:

- SubscriberKey
- Email Address
- Status of 'Unsubscribed'

Comment: Ok, thanks you for you answer , but how can i find customerss that i need to change their statu ? How can i find all of customers who are optout in the master DE but optin in the all sub ?  My sql doesn't works , if you have an other idea ..

Comment: You'll have to query against the _Subscriber data view (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5) to get their current status. Then compare it with your Master_DE. Similar select statement that you have above but with `left join _Subscribers s on a.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey where s.Status = 'unsubscribed'`

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer. The information that I have in the all sub of each BU is different of the information that I have in the parent BU. Indeed we have a preference center for each BU and this preference update only the information in the child BU. So I can't use the data view Subscriber because their information comes from the parent BU. Yes my issue is verry complicated ...

Comment: Use the _Unsubscribe Dataview (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_unsubscribe.htm&type=5) and the `OYBAccountID` field should give you the child BU MID

Comment: Hi , yes , but I need to get the clientes who have an "active" statu , who are optin in the all sub ... I don't have the information in the Unsub data view ..

Comment: To summarize  I can't used the data view Unsub because i would like to find the subscribers and I can't used the data view Subscriber because the information that I have in the all sub of each BU is different of the information that I have in the parent BU. Yes my probelm is complex ...Thanks for your help